# Interesting graphic artifact

Tags: opengl, graphics, minecraft-modding

I was exploring old Minecraft source code when I encountered this:

[image: minecraft glitch]

I just wanted to know what causes such distortion and how to fix it with OpenGL?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about game design.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic, as the aliasing & moiree effects shown here do come up in game & mod development, and avoiding these artifacts is a game development problem. To be able to answer it well though, we'll need more details about what you did, @Jiftoo, to create/expose this artifact. What are we looking at here, is it one quad or many polygons/meshes? Is there particular code you ran or steps you followed to generate this image? Edit your question to include this information and we may be able to spot where the artifacts are coming from (as there are quite a few candidates!)

Comment: Its a [Moiré pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moiré_pattern).

Comment: @DMGregory based on what I see and what I already know, this seems to be the underside of the world from one of the first minecraft versions. The player is very far from it and so the texture details get lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's usually just due to non-existent mipmapping. Turn it on.